# How to stay comfortable in beds found in American hotels?

Tags: usa, hotels, local-customs

I am currently in California for a long business trip. It is surprising how often I wake up here with my feet going past the end of the bed.

The double European beds are about the same size as Queen beds so my issue probably comes from the incredible amount of pillows that you usually find at the top of the bed.

I am not especially tall so how do American people, often taller than European (my feeling), deal with this? My guess is that there are several possibilities:

- People throw somewhere all these pillows and just keep one
- People sleep on the bed diagonally *(I often do this one)*
- People build some kind of corridor in the middle of pillows so that they can squeeze in and fit in the bed

Comment: @Ankur I liked my title ("How to survive American bed ?") Why ? Maybe "How to survive American hotels' beds ?"

Comment: Feet out of bed is my default position. It starts to be a problem when this is not possible by construction...

Comment: @Ugo I was just trying to clarify what the question meant to get it more attention. :)

Comment: I don't really understand this question. Having lots of pillows is not particular to American hotels at all. It's more a function of the star rating of the hotel/how good in thinks it is. I once stayed in a hotel in Madrid with 10 pillows on one bed. And clearly, no-one is forcing you to use them all...

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I don't really agree with you. It is true that 5 star hotels are very uniform and generally tend to satisfy to the customs of there most common customers i.e. Americans. Also many 5 star franchise are American. Maybe it influence other hotels somehow but lot's of pillow is certainly not in hotel quality standard everywhere over the world. By the way I was not really speaking about hotels as I only experiment this in furnished apartments and guest house until now. In this kind of accommodation in France you certainly won't find 6 pillows on your bed.

Comment: @Ugo Still noone forces you to use them all or even leave them on the bed.

Comment: @Karlson And I am pretty sure that if you read my post again you will even find this possibility listed. The question is more about getting cultural insight about something really surprising for some foreigners (believe me). How American people deal with it. I don't know if Mark Mayo is American but is advice of sleeping in fetal position seems amazing (it makes me laugh). Is it a stategy that most American really have?

Comment: @Ugo He's not an American and as an American I don't have a problem getting comfortable in a bed in the hotel.  American people generally deal with it in the following way: if it bothers you get it out of the way, which way you do it is up to you.  But Mark's advise about the fetal position will work if you feel that you should leave all the stuff they put on the bed on the bed.  As far as 6 pillows are concerned think of it this way: 2 people 2 pillows under each head and some women(pregnant especially) like to put 1 between their legs.   Do the math.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many pillows in hotels are decorative. You certainly don't need to keep them all there.

Generally you just put them to the side / on a chair / on the floor until you make the bed in the morning.

It may also be easier if you tend to sleep in the fetal position, rather than stretched out, but it's up to you to find the position that suits you best.

Comment: The standard mattress size for Queen and King is 84" or 7' or about 2m10cm (roughly).

Comment: You make beds in hotels? Most hotels have staff that do that for you. A “long business trip” might involve an extended-stay kind of place that doesn’t, I suppose, but that wasn’t mentioned in the question.